# manejo de cardas con display grid

Tags: css, grid, display

**tengo una serie de cards que contienen imagenes**
estoy trabajando en el diseño responsiva de las cards
el elemento lo tengo en una columna la cual se va reduciendo meidiante el tamaño de pantalla cambia, el problema esta en que no puedo controlar el heigth de las cards

*Codigo grid*

```
.caruselImgGaleriBloc {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quisiera es que el heigth sea el mismo que el width, si el width cambia que lo haga tambien el heigth.

Las dos imágenes se adaptan al tamaño de la columna que lo contiene

*Probe con esta propiedad pero si la imagen es demasiado larga el cuadro se adapta al heigth de la imagen así que por el momento estoy usando media query con heigth específicos*

```
grid-template-rows:
```

Las imágenes que se mostraran pueden ser desde 1 a 16, por lo que el contenedor padre de las imágenes es cambiante

**Quisiera dejar de usar tanta media query**

Comment: prueba con aspect-ratio:1

Comment: @Yussef agradezco tu respuesta me funciono perfecto